# Downloading a file with privileges

Tags: python, django

I want to download a file with Django and check some privileges first (if the user is online, if the user owns the file, etc) so they can't download it with the link itself.

I am aware of `HttpResponse` and I wanted to implement it on a view.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: take a look: http://racingtadpole.com/blog/private-media-with-django/

Answer (score 1):

You can check permissions or everything you need in the view and then return a file in a view using the next code:

```
import mimetypes
import urllib2

def download_view(request, path):
    # Check everything you need to check
    ...

    # Return file
    file_name = urllib2.unquote(path).encode('utf8')
    file_obj = open(file_name, "r")
    m = mimetypes.guess_type(content_path)[0]
    return HttpResponse(file_obj, content_type=m)
```